# Facing Build Error:"No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: UFT_LAUNCHER" while running UFT Tests from VSTS Build

Tags: azure-pipelines, hp-uft

Installed Unified Functional Testing Extension on VSTS from Market Place.Have downloaded a Private Agent on Windows from Agent Pool, while selecting the Default Agent Queue and queuing the Build, Facing a below Error :-
**"No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demand:UFT_LAUNCHER"** Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1

I want to run my UFT Scripts in VSTS and then Publish Reports corresponding to Test Scripts created in Test Hub,I am getting failed at First Step.
Note: I have added Task as "UFT File System Execution"

[image]

Comment: Please also check if you installed these softwares as the system prerequisits says https://github.com/hpsa/ADM-TFS-Extension/wiki/Unified-Functional-Testing-(UFT)-TFS-Extension#system-prerequisites.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Yes I have every Pre- requisites installed on my PC. I had installed the UFT Extension from the Market Place. I don't have any idea how to run the unpack Powershell Script . I am copying the Code in the PS Command Prompt but getting an Error:-

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At line:6 char:22
foreach($item in $zip.items())  
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) , RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: And please also make sure your private agent is specified with the name **Default**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add environment variable manually: System properties>Advanced> Environment variables>Add **UFT_LAUNCHER** key with `[UFT.zip unpacked path]\UFTWorking` value=>Restart build agent.

Comment: I have added the UFT_Launcher as Enironment Variable and take the Value Path as
"C:\Users\P10401685\Desktop\ADM-TFS-Extension-master\ADM-TFS-Extension-master\installation\UFTWorking"
Please confirm if it is correct.

After this I close the Powershell run.cmd window and manually starting the run.cmd again. Can you please tell how to restart the Agent other way.

Comment: If the build agent is running as service, just restart the service directly, otherwise, close the build agent session window and call run.cmd again. If you still don't know how to do it, just restart your machine.