# VSTS > Pipepline> UFT file system execution Task. After setting up the task, I get - Some Targets do not meet all the Task demands - UFT_Launcher

Tags: azure-pipelines

When i'm trying to include Testing Pipeline task in VSTS ADO, the testing task " UFT file System" always throws problem " Missing UFT_Laucher" Can someone tell me what is this UFT_Launcher and where and how do I install it.

Installed all plugins/adddins needed for ALM, UFT execution. 
My UFT scripts are located on a VM machine, installed UFTworking\HPToolslauncher.exe already

[image: issue snapshot]

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440069/facing-build-errorno-agent-found-in-pool-default-which-satisfies-the-specified

Comment: Yes, this is similar. I followed all the steps given in the solution, still facing the same problem. Can someone please help